# How to fix background initialization bug in KivyMD?

Tags: python, kivy

When I use KivyMD, the background seems uninitialized.  For instance, when I try the demo code of MDTapTargetView (see below), the result is a TapTarget on a screen that looks black (looks like it should be white), but the black portion does not refresh itself when the TapTarget is closed (we see previous drawings).  I am testing Kivy v1.11.1 with KivyMD v0.104.1 on Windows 10.  I can work around if I explicitly paint a rectangle in the top canvas.before, but I expect I shouldn't require this.  I don't know how to debug this problem.

```py
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.taptargetview import MDTapTargetView

KV = '''
Screen:
    MDFloatingActionButton:
        id: button
        icon: "plus"
        pos: 10, 10
        on_release: app.tap_target_start()
'''

class TapTargetViewDemo(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        screen = Builder.load_string(KV)
        self.tap_target_view = MDTapTargetView(
            widget=screen.ids.button,
            title_text="This is an add button",
            description_text="This is a description of the button",
            widget_position="left_bottom",
        )
        return screen

    def tap_target_start(self):
        if self.tap_target_view.state == "close":
            self.tap_target_view.start()
        else:
            self.tap_target_view.stop()

TapTargetViewDemo().run()
```

Comment: When I run your code in Windows 10 with Kivy v1.11.1 and KivyMD v0.104.1, it works as expected (white background). I see that my system is using Opengl v4.4.0, sdl2 window provider, and python v3.6.2. What does your system use?

Comment: @JohnAnderson, Thanks for your help. I have Python v3.7.7 (64bit), sdl2, OpenGL version 4.6.0 from Intel (UHD Graphics 620), shading version 4.60.